# Sound cuts out on Android when advert is displayed

Tags: android, audio, unity-game-engine

When my character crosses a finish line, I play a "win" sound. I have an **AudioSource** object to which I simply call **PlayOneShot** and pass it my **AudioClip** as:

```
public void PlayWon() {
    if (GameData.Data.Settings.SoundsOn) {
        AudioSource audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
        audio.Stop();
        audio.PlayOneShot(WinSound);
    }
}
```

My settings for the **AudioSource** are this:

[image]

and the object where this is attached to is loaded in a **Loader** scene which is never destroyed. I ensure this by calling:

```
DontDestroyOnLoad(this);
```

on Awake.

My sound plays fine on iOS, iPhone and iPads. But when testing on my Samsung Galaxy Tab S, the sound plays and then pauses whilst the interstitial advert is displayed and then when dismissed, the sound carries on. I am using Chartboost and Admob and use the basic invoke:

```
    if (Chartboost.hasInterstitial(CBLocation.LevelComplete)) {
        Debug.Log("Showing CB Ad");
        Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocation.LevelComplete);
    }
    else if (_admobInterstitial.IsLoaded()) {
        Debug.Log("Showing Admob Ad");
        _admobInterstitial.Show();
    }
    else {
        Debug.Log("Neither cached, trying CB again");
        Chartboost.cacheInterstitial(CBLocation.LevelComplete);
        Chartboost.showInterstitial(CBLocation.LevelComplete);
    }
```

Any ideas why my sounds cut out on this device? I don't have another Android device to test it on but I'm assuming it's an Android related problem. The sound cuts out on both Chartboost and Admob.

Thanks

Comment: The problem is because admob uses `requestAudioFocus` feature from `AudioManager` to show interstitial videos. I'm not sure if you are using unity for develop your game, and I don't know is is the same method, but i suggest you to implement an `requestAudioFocus` before show the interstitial. Let me know if it help you.

Comment: @diogojme thanks but would the same apply if I'm not using interstitial videos? I have those disabled in Admob currently and on iOS it does work fine. I wanted to avoid requesting audio focus as I didn't want to stop the player from listening to their music or something (assuming that their music would stop)

Comment: I suggest you to show Chartboost interstitial before or after you call `PlayWon()` so the interstitial will not overlay the playWon sound.

Comment: I'd have to do it in a coroutine as Halil suggested as I need to allow time for the sound to finish. Playing the sound after the ad would be weird.

Comment: Yes i think is weird too, and I think is the right solution call the interstitial after play your sound, i will vote up for Halil solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a coroutine for playing the sound. When the coroutine is finished, you can show ads.

```
private IEnumerator PlaySoundAndShowAd()
{
  //play sound
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.0f)
  //show ads or do something.
}
```

Comment: I think this is the what I will have to do. I was hoping there was a better way. Will leave this a few days and accept your answer, cheers!